# T-sql, Running the function whose name is stored in a string variable...with something like exec...and capturing the return value

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, dynamic-sql

The following code works fine (Echo is a user defined function that takes a string and returns a string):

```
Declare @ttt varchar(max) = ''
set @ttt = dbo.Echo('sdf')
print @ttt
```

But the problem is that I have a configuration setting that stores the name of a function in the current database.  The function must take a string parameter and return a string parameter.  So I don't necessarily want to call dbo.Echo.  But I want to call whatever is configured.

So what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
Declare @ttt varchar(max) = ''
Declare @sql varchar(Max)
Declare @func varchar(Max)
Declare @par varchar(max)
set @func = '[dbo].[Echo]'
set @par = 'sdf'
set @sql = 'set @ttt = ' + @func + '(' + '''' + @par + '''' + ')'
exec (@sql)
print @ttt
```

But it tells me that scaler @ttt is not declared!

So I tried like this...

```
Declare @ttt varchar(max) = ''
Declare @sql varchar(Max)
Declare @func varchar(Max)
Declare @par varchar(max)
set @func = '[dbo].[Echo]'
set @par = 'sdf'
set @sql = @func + '(' + '''' + @par + '''' + ')'
set @ttt = exec (@sql)
print @ttt
```

I get 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword exec'

How do I capture the return value and store it in @ttt?

Dear StackExchange:  there is a bug on your website.  I am not allowed to enter the following comment in response to the accepted answer.

Here is the comment with regard to the accepted answer:
it works, but I have to declare @sql as:  Declare @sql nvarchar(Max).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If I understand correctly, you want an output parameter:

```
declare @tttx varchar(max);

set @sql = 'set @ttt = ' + @func + '(' + '''' + @par + '''' + ')'
exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@ttt varchar(max) output',
                   @ttt=@tttx output;

print @tttx;
```

Comment: it works after i set my sql to nvarchar(max).  I don't quite understand why <at sign>ttt = <at sign>ttt output; is required on the syntax.... so I don't quite understand its purpose, but it is required, and it works.  If I put an <at sign> in this comment, I am not allowed to post....

Comment: @HillOfBeans If you have an at-sign in code, e.g. `@ttt = @ttt output`, it works. Click `help` to the right of the comment box for mini-Markdown details. A bit of confusion comes from using `@ttt` as both a variable, declared in the first line, and a parameter to `sp_executesql`. In `@ttt  = @ttt output` the left side is the parameter and the right side is the variable that receives the output. Have a look at Example C at [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples).

Comment: @HillOfBeans . . . This happens to be the syntax for passing parameters into a stored procedure.  The second argument defines the types of the parameters.  The third assigns the values (both going in and out).

Comment: i edited the answer because it becomes confusing.... @ttt=@ttt